# Encryption that can only be decrypted once?

Tags: encryption

I want to encrypt a message so that it can only be decrypted once. I know that we can use nonces to do this when we exchange data over a communication channel, but in my case the cipher text will be stored on a disc.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: This cannot really be done, if you want to do the decryption on a device you don't totally control. Only if you do "decryption as a service" and manage the server doing it very well, it might be doable.

Comment: There might also be some way to do it with quantum mechanics. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer sure, just write your ciphertext using any bunch of photons you might have laying around...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query correctly then you mean that if the decryption is successful then the original message should be destroyed. That said you can do this in such a way that once the password entered is correct the Plain Text should be displayed and the cipher text should be altered beyond recovery. You can write a program to do that. There are some companies which employs such techniques e.g. you can install some features from a CD only once.

If this is a research question then read ahead.
The computing which we do on our computers is called classical computing. A classical computers is independent of the path it chooses to produce the result. However a quantum computer is dependent on how it produced result i.e. the paths available and the paths chosen affects result. So what could have happened but did not heavily affects the outcome. In a quantum system once we take any measurement the state of the system is disturbed. So if you have a ciphertext which is in a quantum system then if you make an observation the system gets disturbed and the original message is lost.
I hope the firs part answered the question but if it did not then I have an upsetting information for you, the quantum cryptography is a theoretical model which has not been fully practically realized(as far as I know).

Comment: In the first case what prevents the user from simply copying the ciphertext?

Comment: One way could be read protection. I am not sure about the implementation.